# Descer scroll até o fim da div

Tags: jquery, rolamento

Estou com o código

```
1 - $("#fluxo-msg").load('fluxo-mensagem.php', {fake:fake, user:user});
2 -
3 - $('html, body').animate({
4 -    scrollTop: $("#vemaqui").offset().top
5 - }, 1000);
```

Na **linha 1** eu carrego um arquivo que contém o conteúdo que o usuário irá visualizar

Na **linha 3,4,5** eu *tento* fazer com que depois que carregar a página, ela desça até a `div` **#vemaqui**. O problema é que carrega o arquivo, mas o scroll não desce até a `div` **#vemaqui** (que está dentro do conteúdo que será carregado pela função `load()`). A `div` **#fluxo-msg** que é responsável por receber o conteúdo tem um limite de `height** de **300px** e como o conteúdo é grande, eu coloquei um`overflow: auto` então depois que passa dos 300px ele gera um scroll.

Comment: Alisson, julgo que o seu problema aqui é idêntico à pergunta que coloquei aqui ^. No fundo você tem de correr esse código sincrono com o ajax, que é por natureza assincrono. Assim esse código tem de estar dentro da callback do `load` para só correr quando o conteudo tiver carregado e não antes como acontece agora.

Comment: Na verdade +/- semelhante a esta sua outra pergunta que eu respondi tb: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/28973/129

Comment: @Sergio Verdade. Muito obrigado!